# Why won't the algorithm to detect cycles in undirected graphs work to detect cycles in directed graph

Tags: python, graph

So here's my code here, it's meant to detect cycles from undirected graphs, sources say it won't work on detecting cycles on directed graphs. But I really can't think of any scenario where it don't work through?:

```
# Input: a graph G = (V, E) with n vertices and m edges
# Output: true if G contains a cycle, false otherwise

# Initialize a list of boolean values to mark the visited vertices
visited = [False] * n

# Initialize a list of integers to store the parent of each vertex in the DFS tree
parent = [-1] * n

# Define a recursive function to perform DFS from a given vertex
def dfs(v):
  # Mark the current vertex as visited
  visited[v] = True

  # Loop through the adjacent vertices of v
  for u in G.adj(v):
    # If u is not visited, then recursively explore u and update its parent
    if not visited[u]:
      parent[u] = v
      dfs(u)
    # If u is visited and u is not the parent of v, then a cycle is found
    elif u != parent[v]:
      return True

  # Return false if no cycle is found
  return False

# Loop through all the vertices of the graph
for v in V:
  # If v is not visited, then perform DFS from v
  if not visited[v]:
    # If DFS returns true, then a cycle is found
    if dfs(v):
      return True

# Return false if no cycle is found in the graph
return False
```

I tried it on most directed graphs I tested, it worked well?

for example, I tested it on directed graph

```
G = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
     'B': ['D'],
     'C': ['A'],
     'D': ['C']}
```

and it successfully detect the cycle using the "undirected cycle" algorithm